# Extracting data from HTTP Response - Angular 5

Tags: httpclient, angular5

I am trying to extract lat and lng values form the resulting JSON, from HTTP response -

```
  lat: any;
  lng: any;
  geoResult: any;

  public getGeoCoordinates(store) {
    let apiUrl = '/assets/GoogleGeoCoordinates.json';
    this.http.get(apiUrl).subscribe( resp => {
        this.geoResult = resp;
    });
  }
```

from above method, I am trying to capture the values as follows

```
  if (resp['status'] == 'OK' && resp['results']['length'] > 0) {
        this.lat = resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
        this.lng = resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
   }
```

if I use alert(), like alert('Latitude : ' + resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']);

alert is showing the value.

If I store that value in 'this.lat' variable, I am getting 'undefined'

can someone help me, to understand to get the values from the json HTTP response

JSON file content - GoogleGeoCoordinates.json

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "120",
                    "short_name": "120",
                    "types": [
                        "street_number"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "West 56th Street",
                    "short_name": "W 56th St",
                    "types": [
                        "route"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Manhattan",
                    "short_name": "Manhattan",
                    "types": [
                        "political",
                        "sublocality",
                        "sublocality_level_1"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "New York",
                    "short_name": "New York",
                    "types": [
                        "locality",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "New York County",
                    "short_name": "New York County",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "New York",
                    "short_name": "NY",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "United States",
                    "short_name": "US",
                    "types": [
                        "country",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "10019",
                    "short_name": "10019",
                    "types": [
                        "postal_code"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "formatted_address": "120 W 56th St, New York, NY 10019, USA",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 40.7640254,
                    "lng": -73.97896
                },
                "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 40.7653743802915,
                        "lng": -73.97761101970849
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 40.7626764197085,
                        "lng": -73.98030898029151
                    }
                }
            },
            "place_id": "ChIJE4YK3PlYwokRybTACneYny4",
            "types": [
                "street_address"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

Comment: are u declare `lat` value on top. `public lat: any;`

Comment: you have to share more of the code that is involved. Context of your question is not clear. So just add full code for your component including how you declare lat/lng etc

Comment: here is declarations -

  lat: any;
  lng: any;
  geoResult: any;

Comment: here is declarations -

  lat: any;
  lng: any;
  geoResult: any;


Attached is the JSON file, 'GoogleGeoCoordinates.json' -


Please let me know, if you need any additional details.

Thank You

Comment: added JSON content and variables declared above in the original post (as I have made edit to it)

Answer (score 0):

I have assigned the values outside the 'subscribe', and it seems started working.

working code as follows -

```
public getGeoCoordinates(store) {
    let apiUrl = '/assets/GoogleGeoCoordinates.json';

    this.http.get(apiUrl).subscribe( resp => {
        this.geoResult = resp;

        });
    this.lat = this.geoResult['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']; 
    this.lng = this.geoResult['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
  }
```

Comment: also unsubscribing variables and handling cache also played its role.